# Import crash logs from iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash, dsym

I need to retrieve current crash logs for the build, which is in App Store or symbolicate crash logs from devices for this build. All builds were sent from another machine, so i do not have them. In iTunesConnect i can't neither download any build nor download dSYM file (**"Includes Symbols"** is set to **"YES"**).

Is there any way to view current crash logs?

**P.S**: Please, do not suggest any solution like Crashlytics, because i need **current crash logs**, that should be already saved in iTunesConnect.

Comment: It's seems there is not solution for this now. i managed to get the build from another developer and through this build got reports.